# Babel support for addEventListener once? (3rd arg options object)

Tags: babeljs

I tested and it works, but I'm not sure if it's my browser. Does babel support `addEventListener` with 3rd argument as an object? I want to set `once:true`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

target.addEventListener(type, listener[, options]);

```
options Optional
    An options object that specifies characteristics about the event listener. The available options are:

        capture: A Boolean that indicates that events of this type will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree.  
        once: A Boolean indicating that the listener should be invoked at most once after being added. If it is true, the listener would be removed automatically when it is invoked.
        passive: A Boolean indicating that the listener will never call preventDefault(). If it does, the user agent should ignore it and generate a console warning.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Babel doesn't hand things like this. Babel attempts to make standard ES6+ syntax and library functionality work in older browsers. The DOM API, of which `addEventListener` is part, is not defined by the ECMAScript language specification, so it is unrelated to Babel.

You'd want to load a DOM polyfill like https://github.com/WebReflection/dom4.

Comment: Ah. Thanks logan! I thought it was ES6, but it makes sense, the DOM is seperate from the ES6.